# How can I overlay image on top of video with resize?

Tags: html, css, overlay

Hello I have been trying to overlay an image on top of a video in a resizable container. I have tried many examples but each seems specific to the implementation.. My latest test is here https://jsfiddle.net/1Lfsy95w/ I can't get the video size to be correct and the image is out of the bounds.. Both should remain 16:9 aspect ratio, and be be resized of parent

```
#player-overlay {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;      
    z-index: 4;      
    opacity: .5;
}

#OutputVideo {      
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:red;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    height:auto;        
}
```

And the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="player-overlay" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580757468214-c73f7062a5cb"/>
  <video id="OutputVideo">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm"> 
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are set with with respect to the nearest non-static ancestor. You need to set position on your wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

To keep the image from pushing the wrapper below the video, hide overflow:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9h8ksgby/)

You can simplify things a bit by 1) putting the image as a background, and 2) moving the overlay after the video. This gives you more sizing flexibility and eliminates the need to fiddle with z-index.

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#player-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  background-image: url(https://...);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <video controls id="OutputVideo">
    <source src="http://....webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
  <div id="player-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9h8ksgby/13/)